# What is this orb attached to my object?

Tags: object-mode

I have an orb that just appeared attached to my object in Object Mode. It disappears in Edit Mode. If you zoom in the orb stays the same size and you can see it is attached at a specific vertex. When I go to Edit Mode and delete the vertex the orb attaches to a nearby vertex when I go back into Object Mode. If I export to an stl it doesn't appear on the file. How do I get rid of it?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about the big sphere it's probably a particle that you've created (if your object is very small it makes the default particle look big), go in the *Properties panel > Particle*, and delete *ParticleSettings*:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!